# Highcharts JS, in an Android WebView, is redrawing the chart after first pinching to zoom. Afterwards interaction works fine

Tags: highcharts

We were having issues with Highcharts on Android not working quite right. The zooming interaction stopped working properly after the user interacted with the legend. There was a workaround mentioned here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/18062#issuecomment-1700936117. After implementing that workaround is when we noticed the issue mentioned in the title. What happens is the line data will animatedly load in. If you pinch to zoom in, when you let go the line data will redo that initial loading animation in and zoom will reset to the initial layout.

Comment: Since the workaround was sent in issues, it's best to wait for an answer there